# Patch a variable inside a method of a class instance

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, django-class-based-views

I am trying to understand how patching works and I am testing with pytest a Django View:

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    pass
```

test_view.py

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
from .views import MyLoginView

rf = RequestFactory()

def test_login(rf):
    request = rf.get(reverse('myapp:login'))
    response = MyLoginView.as_view()(request)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

This fails because this View calls the database in order to get the current Site using the function [`get_current_site()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L95):

`Failed: Database access not allowed`

How can I mock `get_current_site()` to avoid the database hit?

An idea is to use a factory with pytest-factoryboy.

I managed to mock `LoginView.get_context_data` but I cannot go deeper:

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
from .views import MyLoginView

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from pytest_factoryboy import register
from unittest.mock import patch

rf = RequestFactory()


class SiteFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Site

register(SiteFactory)


def test_login_social(rf, site_factory):
    request = rf.get(reverse('myapp:login'))
    with patch(
        # 'django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView.get_context_data',  # This is wrong
        'django.contrib.auth.views.get_current_site',  # Solution: Patch where it is imported, this works!
        return_value=site_factory(name='example.com'),
    ):
        response = CommunityLoginView.as_view()(request)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

---

### **Edit**

The solution is to patch the method beeing called, at the scope where it is [imported](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L14):

`with patch('django.contrib.auth.views.get_current_site')`

---

Here an error occurs due to the `context_data` being a `<class 'django.contrib.sites.models.Site'>`

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. `pytest` only allows a [database access](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html), if you explicitly mark the test function that we will hit the database. Without that information, `pytest` will run the test without having constructed a database for tests. I recommend to use [`pytest-django`](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the provided decorator [`pytest.mark.django_db`](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest-mark-django-db-request-database-access).
2. You have added the [Site-Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/) to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. This app is optional, but useful if you serve multiple different pages from a single Django application. There was a time when the Site-Framework was mandatory, but since it is optional I rarely include in my `INSTALLED_APPS`. Maybe you should leave it out to.

---

EDIT: **Mocking**

Sure, mocking should work as well, since every object in python is mockable ([even small numbers](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2441cv/can_you_change_the_value_of_1/)). Keep in mind that you have to patch where the module/function [is imported](https://howchoo.com/g/owy4mzvhn2n/unit-testing-in-python-tips-tricks-and-gotchas#remember-to-patch-the-correct-path) because it's bound to the local scope.

To find the right location, you could either search the [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/search?l=Python&q=get_current_site), see how it is used and how to patch it correctly or try to drop into `PDB`. I am not sure which way will work, but I provide you with 2 options:

1. `pytest --pdb`
2. `python -m pdb pytest`. This will instantly open the debugger and you have to `continue` once. `pytest` will now run until the first exception occurs and `PDB` will start automatically.

You can now use `bt` (backtrace), `u` (walk stack up), `l` (show source code) and `d` (walk stack down) to find the location of the database access.

---

EDIT2: **factoryboy**

If you are using `factoryboy`, it depends on the [build strategy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#strategies) whether it tries to access the database or not. The default strategy is `.create()`, which writes to the database.

It should work if you use `site_factory.build()`, since this will not access your database.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I do not intend to test Django. This is just a tricky example to understand 'how' and how far `patch` can make it.

Comment: @raratiru I updated my answer to help in finding the correct way to mock the given function. Maybe there are also multiple accesses to the database beside `get_current_site()`.

Comment: Thank you for the pdb trick and the links. I managed to mock `LoginView.get_context_data` but I cannot go deeper and find either [`current_site` or `get_current_site`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L95)

Comment: ahh... now I see the problem! I somehow missed that you try to create a `Site` object using `factoryboy`. If you create an instance with `factoryboy`, it depends on the  [build strategy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#strategies) whether it tries to access the database or not. The default strategy is `.create()`, which writes to the database.

It should work if you use `site_factory.build()`, since this does not access your database.

Comment: Thank you, it does not hit the database, because I managed to patch the `get_context_data` method without hitting the database. Actually, I cannot patch the variable defined inside that method. `class()` -> `def method(self)` -> `variable = call_to_another_module()`.

Comment: But aren't you using `site_factory(name='example.com')` in your test? If so `site_factory(name='example.com')` hits the database, but `site_factory.build(name='example.com')` will not.

Comment: I gave it a try. The error message either way is `AttributeError: <function LoginView.get_context_data at 0x7f345156b048> does not have the attribute 'current_site'`. I suspect that we need an instance of LoginView and not the class and the `get_context_data` method has to be called with `request` as an argument. How can this be done? Supposing that `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView.return_value` brings an instance in, how about the `request` argument?

Comment: OK ... as you said! I had to patch it at the module where it was imported: `django.contrib.auth.views.get_current_site` and not through the `LoginView`. Thank you!